# How to add href link for files in another folder in Eclipse?

Tags: html, spring-mvc

I know this is a very basic question but I am struggling a low for this problem. This is my project hierarchy and I am having an `href` on the home button which would direct to the **contact-us.html** page in my **html** folder but I am not getting the path which I should write. It always shows error 404.

I have tried

- `/ZingyBeesTest/html/contact-us.html`
- `/ZingyBeesTest/WEB-INF/html/contact-us.html`
- `/html/contact-us.html`

and many more. What should I write? I am facing the same problem with images. That is why I have pasted all the images in the same directory as my index.html.

[image: Project Hierarchy]

**EDIT :**
One of my mistakes was that the web.xml and servlet file must be present in the WEB-INF folder and not in the Web Content folder. But the links still do not work.

Comment: What about `/ZingyBeesTest/WebContent/WEB-INF/html/contact-us.html`?

Comment: Still HTTP status 404!

Comment: `/WEB-INF/html/contact-us.html` ?

Comment: How you serve this project? Using http? Just opening `index.html` in Chrome (Using `file:///` schema)

Comment: @mituw16 ..This should work but sadly it does not.

Comment: @MoshFeu I am running it on localhost. When I open the file, the link for index.html is `file:///C:/Users/Shashank/Desktop/ZB%20Gitlab/ZB-website/ZingyBeesTest/WebContent/index.html` and for the contact-us.html is `file:///C:/Users/Shashank/Desktop/ZB%20Gitlab/ZB-website/ZingyBeesTest/WebContent/WEB-INF/html/contact-us.html` .